# Is there a better way to iterate over this multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the Solr search engine. It returns my search results like so:

```
array(2) {
  ["responseHeader"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["status"]=>
    int(0)
    ["QTime"]=>
    int(1)
    ["params"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["wt"]=>
      string(3) "php"
      ["start"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["q"]=>
      string(7) "monitor"
      ["version"]=>
      string(3) "2.2"
      ["rows"]=>
      string(2) "10"
    }
  }
  ["response"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["numFound"]=>
    int(2)
    ["start"]=>
    int(0)
    ["docs"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(11) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(6) "VA902B"
        ["name"]=>
        string(49) "ViewSonic VA902B - flat panel display - TFT - 19""
        ["manu"]=>
        string(15) "ViewSonic Corp."
        ["weight"]=>
        float(190.4)
        ["price"]=>
        float(279.95)
        ["price_c"]=>
        string(10) "279.95,USD"
        ["popularity"]=>
        int(6)
        ["inStock"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["store"]=>
        string(18) "45.17614,-93.87341"
        ["cat"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "electronics"
          [1]=>
          string(7) "monitor"
        }
        ["features"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(75) "19" TFT active matrix LCD, 8ms response time, 1280 x 1024 native resolution"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "3007WFP"
        ["name"]=>
        string(34) "Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP"
        ["manu"]=>
        string(10) "Dell, Inc."
        ["includes"]=>
        string(9) "USB cable"
        ["weight"]=>
        float(401.6)
        ["price"]=>
        float(2199)
        ["price_c"]=>
        string(8) "2199,USD"
        ["popularity"]=>
        int(6)
        ["inStock"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["store"]=>
        string(18) "43.17614,-90.57341"
        ["cat"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "electronics"
          [1]=>
          string(7) "monitor"
        }
        ["features"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(71) "30" TFT active matrix LCD, 2560 x 1600, .25mm dot pitch, 700:1 contrast"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am capturing this response inside a variable called `$results`. On my page I am doing a vardump to get each result set like so:

```
foreach($results['response'] as $result) {
    if(is_array($result)) {
        foreach($result as $v) {
            var_dump($v);   
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of that:

```
array(11) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "VA902B"
  ["name"]=>
  string(49) "ViewSonic VA902B - flat panel display - TFT - 19""
  ["manu"]=>
  string(15) "ViewSonic Corp."
  ["weight"]=>
  float(190.4)
  ["price"]=>
  float(279.95)
  ["price_c"]=>
  string(10) "279.95,USD"
  ["popularity"]=>
  int(6)
  ["inStock"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["store"]=>
  string(18) "45.17614,-93.87341"
  ["cat"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "electronics"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "monitor"
  }
  ["features"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(75) "19" TFT active matrix LCD, 8ms response time, 1280 x 1024 native resolution"
  }
}

array(12) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "3007WFP"
  ["name"]=>
  string(34) "Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP"
  ["manu"]=>
  string(10) "Dell, Inc."
  ["includes"]=>
  string(9) "USB cable"
  ["weight"]=>
  float(401.6)
  ["price"]=>
  float(2199)
  ["price_c"]=>
  string(8) "2199,USD"
  ["popularity"]=>
  int(6)
  ["inStock"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["store"]=>
  string(18) "43.17614,-90.57341"
  ["cat"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "electronics"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "monitor"
  }
  ["features"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(71) "30" TFT active matrix LCD, 2560 x 1600, .25mm dot pitch, 700:1 contrast"
  }
}
```

This is exactly what I need but I was wondering if there is a more elegent way to get it than my "nested foreach loop and is array check" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($results['response']['docs'] as $result) {
   ...
}
```